# Sustituir cláusula CASE en SELECT por un TABLA

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una serie de varias consultas en un sistema que alguien mas hizo. Todos están en código duro.

Todos tienen la siguiente estructura:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, -- varios datos extra diferentes en cada una
  CASE 
    WHEN ALGO >= 20 AND ALGO < 30 THEN 1
    WHEN ALGO >= 30 AND ALGO < 40 THEN 2
    WHEN ALGO >= 40 AND ALGO < 50 THEN 3
    WHEN ALGO >= 50 AND ALGO < 60 THEN 4
    ELSE 0
  END AS INDICADOR -- un indicador que depende de unos rangos
FROM .... -- aqui puede ir una tabla o un union o un join
```

Tengo como 20 aproximadamente. El problema es que los datos a comparar son dinámicos. Digamos que cada cierto tiempo cambian, por ejemplo, cada 6 meses o cada 3 meses o cada año.

Lo que he agregado hasta el momento son varias tablas de estos parámetros, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM PARAMETROS_VENTAS1
```

Da

```
id| minimo| maximo| valor
1 | 15    | 25    | 1
2 | 25    | 30    | 2
3 | 30    | 45    | 3
4 | 45    | 50    | 4
```

Así que intenté hacer un subquery, pero no funciona para varios datos. Si le doy `WHERE id = cualquiera`, sí funciona.

```
SELECT acol, bcol, 
(  select valor from test.PARAMETROS_VENTAS1
   where a.columna between min and max )
FROM test.tabla_a a
where id > 32 -- id > 32 regresa varios registros asi que no funciona
-- id  = 33 si funciona
```

¿Cómo podría resolverlo?

---

[EDIT]

Encontre otro caso, de un query que es un poco mas complejo, ya que tiene dos case anidados, mas o menos asi:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, -- varios datos extra diferentes en cada una
  CASE 
    WHEN ALGO >= 20 AND ALGO < 30 THEN 
        case 
            then otro >= 1 and otro < 5 then 10  --
            then otro >= 5 and otro < 10 then 20 --
        end
    WHEN ALGO >= 30 AND ALGO < 40 THEN 
        case 
            then otro >= 1 and otro < 5 then 12  -- 
            then otro >= 5 and otro < 10 then 22 --
        end
    WHEN ALGO >= 40 AND ALGO < 50 THEN 
        case 
            then otro >= 1 and otro < 5 then 13  --
            then otro >= 5 and otro < 10 then 23 --
        end
    WHEN ALGO >= 50 AND ALGO < 60 THEN 
        case 
            then otro >= 1 and otro < 5 then 14  --
            then otro >= 5 and otro < 10 then 24 --
        end
    ELSE 0
  END AS INDICADOR -- un indicador que depende de unos rangos
FROM .... -- aqui puede ir una tabla o un union o un join
```

Comment: El problema es que la tabla es ambigua. Por ejemplo, el valor máximo de uno es el mínimo del otro...si corrigieras eso para que sea determinista, podrías hacerlo con una subconsulta. ¿Se entiende lo que digo?

Comment: No entiendo bien para qué sirve esta parte: `where id > 32`. Qué es lo que estas filtrando?

Comment: Pablo, si claro, en teoria nunca pensaba guardar los valores como 24.99 y 25, pero para el ejemplo solo use el 25

Comment: La parte del > 32 solo es un ejemplo de filtro que devuelve muchos valores, mientras que id = 32 solo regresa uno

Comment: Pense que necesitabas un rango de Id dentro de la tabla y que de ese rango te traiga un valor.

Answer (score 1):

El problema principal es que usas `BETWEEN` que compara los valores de forma inclusiva. Por ejemplo, si el valor de tu columna es `25`, al usar `between`, va a corresponder a los 2 registros siguientes (que no es lo que quieres):

```
id| minimo| maximo| valor
1 | 15    | 25    | 1
2 | 25    | 30    | 2
```

Mas bien, siguiendo la lógica de tu expresión `CASE`, el valor debería estar entre `minimo` (**inclusivo**) y `maximo` (**exclusivo**). Siguiendo esta lógica correctamente, nunca tendrás el problema de devolver mas de un registro a la vez de la tabla `PARAMETROS_VENTAS1`. El uso de `BETWEEN` no es adecuado para esto. Mas bien puedes usar:

```
where a.columna >= minimo -- inclusivo
  and a.columna < maximo  -- exclusivo
```

Un problema segundario es que no estás manejando el caso donde el valor no corresponde a ninguno de tus registros, el equivalente del `ELSE 0` en tu expresión `CASE`. Puedes usar `COALESCE(..., 0)` para esto. O sea, que te devuelva `0` si no encuentra registro en `PARAMETROS_VENTAS1` (`null`).

Si sigo el estílo de tu subconsulta, puedes hacer la consulta de esta forma:

```
select a, b, c, d,
       coalesce((select p.valor
                   from parametros_venta1 p
                  where t.a >= p.minimo
                    and t.a < p.maximo), 0) as indicador
  from tabla_a t
 order by id;
```

Otra manera de hacerlo, que puede ofrecer un mejor rendimiento dependiendo de tus datos, es usando un `LEFT JOIN` en vez de una subconsulta:

```
select t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d,
       coalesce(p.valor, 0) as indicador
  from tabla_a t
  left join parametros_venta1 p
    on t.a >= p.minimo
   and t.a < p.maximo
 order by t.id;
```

Aquí te dejo un enlace para que puedas probar las 2 consultas: [**Demostración**](http://rextester.com/HSIM85486).

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, solo que tengo un detalle, acabo de encontrar otro caso, donde hay CASE anidados, no se si deba abrir otra pregunta, o mejor edito esta

Comment: @dr_der: Si la pregunta es en realidad diferente, es mejor abrir una nueva pregunta. Es mas, eso da la oportunidad a que mas personas vean la nueva pregunta y te ayuden.

Comment: Pues al final si edite la pregunta, no se como podrias ese query en especifico